# jboss 5 startup time?

Tags: jboss5.x

Jboss 4.2.2 taking 30 to 40 secs to start up. but Jboss 5 taking like 1 min 20 sec for starting up.
is this normal time or may it be reduced?

Comment: Yes, it's normal, it's bigger and more complicated.